# Virtual phone number

Tags: anonymity

I want to set up an account for a certain service while remaining anonymous. This service requires phone activation and where I live it not possible to activate a sim card without submitting id to the telco provider (that's just the law here).

Can I use some sort of virtual phone number get get around this? It doesn't matter which country code is being used (like US will do just fine).

I looked at http://k7.net but it no longer accept new registrations.

Comment: HeyWire is an app for android which gives you an US number to receive SMS on. Not sure this is what you are looking for as you still need a phone for this.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is: "will a virtual phone number work?" or "can you recommend a service that provides virtual phone numbers?" Please note that product/service recommendations are off-topic on the site.